# Return type dependent on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

### Intro

I want to represent sampled functions (large vectors basically) that can have
scalar, or vector values. (scalar to some extent being a special case of a
1 element vector)

I want to have an interface that allows writing stuff like
`g[i] = 2*f[i] + f[j]`. Hence, for a vector valued function `f[i]` needs to
return an object which can do arithmetic and assignment on the vector elements.
However, in the scalar case this system should be as efficient as a simple
vector. So, ideally `f[i]` should return something that is equivalent to e.g. a
reference to a `double` (performance wise).

My approach so far is to have a class `Function` with a template parameter
`extent` which can be either `One`, or `Large`.

```
template<typename T, Extent extent>  // extent is either `One`, or `Large`
class Function;
```

It defines an `operator[]` which returns either a reference to the data type
(if `extent` is `One`), or a `View` object (if `extent` is `Large`), that
behaves like a vector.

```
// If `extent` is `One`:  `Accessor_` is a `T&`.
// If `extent` is `Large`:  `Accessor_` is a `View`.
Accessor_ operator[](int i) {
    return make_accessor<T, extent>(data_[stride_*i]);
}
```

The function `make_accessor` is a template function with two specializations.

```
/// Convinience function to create an accessor.
template<typename T, Extent extent>
Accessor<T, extent> &make_accessor(T &data);
template<typename T>
Accessor<T, Extent::One> &make_accessor(T &data) { return data; }
template<typename T>
Accessor<T, Extent::Large> &make_accessor(T &data) { return View<T>(&data); }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Technically, it compiles. However, I get a
linker error saying that `make_accessor` is not defined.

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -o elem_type elem_type.cc -std=c++11
/tmp/ccz3zgwS.o: In function `Function<double, (Extent)0>::operator[](int)':
elem_type.cc:(.text._ZN8FunctionIdL6Extent0EEixEi[_ZN8FunctionIdL6Extent0EEixEi]+0x30):
undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::Accessor_<double, View<double>,
(Extent)0>::Type& make_accessor<double, (Extent)0>(double&)'
/tmp/ccz3zgwS.o: In function `Function<double, (Extent)1>::operator[](int)':
elem_type.cc:(.text._ZN8FunctionIdL6Extent1EEixEi[_ZN8FunctionIdL6Extent1EEixEi]+0x30):
undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::Accessor_<double, View<double>,
(Extent)1>::Type& make_accessor<double, (Extent)1>(double&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [elem_type] Error 1
```

Googling this error doesn't give me any hints. All I can find are questions
where people put the implementation into a separate `.cpp` file. However, this
is not the case here. **Everything** is in one single `.cpp` file. So, I don't
understand how an undefined reference is possible. I tried both, GCC 4.8.1, and
clang 3.3. The linker error appears in both cases (GNU ld 2.23.2). I also tried
explicitely template instantiating `make_accessor` it didn't help.

### My Questions

I have to questions:

1. What causes this linker error, and how can I fix it?
2. <s>Do you think there is an easier way of achieving what I described above?</s>

**EDIT** Question 1 is solved. (See below). However, the code has a whole lot more issues. I'll come back to 2 in a new question once everything is fixed.

### The Full Code

```
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


/// The extent of elements of a function.
enum class Extent { One, Large };

/// Convert a precise size to an extent.
constexpr Extent extentof(int size) {
    return size == 1 ? Extent::One :
        size > 1 ? Extent::Large :
        throw std::logic_error("Invalid size");
}


/// View into a part of an array.
template<typename T>
class View {
public:
    View() = default;
    View(T *data, int size) : data_(data), size_(size) {
        assert(data_ != nullptr);
    }

    int size() const { return size_; }
    T &operator[](int i) {
        assert(data_ != nullptr);
        assert(i < size_);
        return data_[i];
    }

private:
    T *data_;
    int size_;
};


namespace {
template<typename T, class View, Extent extent>
struct Accessor_;
template<typename T, class View>
struct Accessor_<T, View, Extent::One> {
    typedef T Type;
};
template<typename T, class View>
struct Accessor_<T, View, Extent::Large> {
    typedef View Type;
};
}

/// The type to access a single element.
template<typename T, Extent extent>
using Accessor = typename Accessor_<T, View<T>, extent>::Type;

/// Convinience function to create an accessor.
template<typename T, Extent extent>
Accessor<T, extent> &make_accessor(T &data);
template<typename T>
Accessor<T, Extent::One> &make_accessor(T &data) { return data; }
template<typename T>
Accessor<T, Extent::Large> &make_accessor(T &data) { return View<T>(&data); }


/// A function whos values have an extent.
template<typename T, Extent extent>
class Function {
    typedef Accessor<T, extent> Accessor_;
public:
    Function() = default;
    explicit Function(int size, int elem_size=1)
        : data_(size*elem_size), size_(size), stride_(elem_size) {
        assert(extent == extentof(elem_size));
    }

    Accessor_ &operator[](int i) {
        return make_accessor<T, extent>(data_[stride_*i]);
    }

private:
    typedef std::vector<T> Store;
    Store data_;
    int size_;
    int stride_;
};


int main() {
    Function<double, Extent::One> func1(3);
    Function<double, Extent::Large> func2(3, 2);

    func1[1] = 1;  // Should change the value stored inside `func1`.
    func2[0][1] = 2;  // Should change the value stored inside `func2`.
}
```

Comment: Please reformat the question: Write the question context (Your "intro") with code examples, and simplify the code provided to just focus on the problem only.

Comment: @Manu343726 Sebastian Redl actually found the right answer. I tried to reformat the question a little anyway, hoping that it will help others with the same problem in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't partially specialize function templates. What you're doing is adding additional overloads that you're not calling. The linker error is pointing out that the compiler tried to use the first templates (those with two parameters), but there aren't any definitions for them.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.